# KB3AIK_EN.iso remove/delete not possible because used by service

Tags: windows-7

i needed and installed "The Windows® Automated Installation Kit (AIK) for Windows® 7" where a 1.66GB iso file belonged to.

Now i deinstalled/removed the software also used c cleaner. 
But still i can't delete the file.
The Information I got is, the file is used by a service but I can't find out which one started this file.
any suggestion and help to find the service to kill the servie and delete the file (KB3AIK_EN.iso)?

have a nice day
vinc

Comment: The ISO is probably mounted...

Comment: yes it is but who and why?

Comment: Then unmount it. Something must have mounted it.

Comment: it is "mounted" like a DVD drive, if i eject the dvd it is still not possible to delete the iso file

Comment: Unmounted it with the software that is mounting it. Or mount another ISO on the same virtual CD drive.

Comment: as i wrote befor i don't know which service is loading the iso file

Answer (score 0):

Run [ProcessExplorer](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653.aspx) and use <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd> to search for the open handle to the file **KB3AIK_EN.iso**. In the lower pane you can make a rightclick on the handle and select to close the handle.

Comment: nice tool this prcessExplorer - i found the file but if i kill it i got a blut screen

Comment: which process had the handle?